# Flutter Firestore: Prevent duplicate increment when two devices like simultaneously

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my Flutter app, there is a counting like button. When a user likes, I check the user's '**isLike**' bool value in Firestore and then use "FieldValue.increment(1)" to increment the number of likes.

However, when two devices are logged in with the same account and **like at the same moment**, the number of likes may be **increased by 2** (because the bool value may not have been updated yet). How to solve it?

```dart
DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).get();
if (snapshot['isLike'] == false) {
  db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({
    'isLike': true,
  });
  db.collection('items').doc('item').update({
    'likeCount': FieldValue.increment(1),
  });
}
```

Comment: Use a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) to read and update documents atomically so you won't have a race condition.

Comment: If you're worried about the size of a document then you should consider using [this](https://extensions.dev/extensions/alexmamo/firestore-document-size) Firebase Extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferred way of handling this use-case is to store what user voted on each item. That way you can not only prevent problems with concurrent updates, but can also prevent the same user from liking a post multiple times.

For example, you can add an array field to the item document with the UID of the users who liked that item:

```
"item12345": {
  ... //  your existing fields
  likedBy: [
    "uidForAndy",
    "uidForPuf"
  ]
}
```

With the above you can easily see that two people liked the item, but you can also prevent them from liking it again by using the [`array-union` operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array). If I were to vote for a second time, the `array-union` call would detect that the `uidForPuf` value already exists, and leave `likedBy` unmodified.

---

If you want to store upvotes and downvotes, you could use a map-field instead, and store a +1 or -1 value:

```
"item12345": {
  ... //  your existing fields
  votes: {
    "uidForAndy": +1,
    "uidForPuf": +1
  }
}
```

Now you'd use `.` notation to [update the fields in the nested object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects), and can sum over the votes map to determine the vote total.

---

Storing this information in the item document limits how many votes you can store, as a document can be at most 1MB in size. If this is a problem for your use-case, you can take the same approach but then store the information in separate documents in a subcollection. So each such nested document would use the UID as its document ID, which also prevents it being duplicated (as a document ID is by definition unique within its collection).